# Accessing relationship in Yii

Tags: php, yii

I have a database where i use a link table to link client with tarriff and then again link tarriff to tarriffdetails. Below is the structure.

```
Client      BaseTarriff     BaseTariffDetails

ClientId    TarriffId       TarriffDetailsId            
            ClientId        TarriffCode
                            TarriffId
```

I want to access the basetariffdetails using the Client model like so:

```
$models = Client::model()->with('tarriff')->findByPk(1);

$model->tarriff->baseTariffDetails->TarriffCode;
```

The relationship between the models is as follows:

```
Client
    'tariff' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'BaseTariff', 'TarriffId'),

BaseTarriff
    'baseTariffDetails' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'BaseTariffDetails', 'TarriffId'),
```

Thanks.

Comment: If a `BaseTarriff` has *many* `BaseTariffDetails`, `$model->tariff->baseTariffDetails` will be *an array*, not an object. You'll need to inspect that array to find the one detail record you're looking for. (Sidenote: switching between `tarriff` and `tariff` will give you a lot of headaches. Pick one or the other and stick with it.)

Comment: Awesome. I get what you mean. Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If BaseTarrif only has one BaseTariffDetails  you can use BaseTarrif->BaseTarifDetails , however if if BaseTarrif has many BaseTariffDetails you will have to iterate trough $model which is where you will get the result from the model.

here I pasted an example of my code , this is the first case

```
$reservation = Reservation::model()->searchTrack($track->number);
 $reservation->status;                
 $reservation->number;
```

the second case will be something like

```
 $reservation = Reservation::model()->searchTrack($track->number);

   foreach ($reservation as $key => $value) {
         $value->status;
         $value->number
         }
```

hope this will help you.